# How can I display contents of lists without allowing changes?

Tags: list, view

I'm building a rota system in SharePoint 2010 using a contacts list for each team and then pulling the contact detail into a separate custom list, via lookup, for each team to define the rota schedule.

At some point I'd like to consolidate the various lists to provide an all encompassing view of who's on call and when. What's the best method to achieve this please and how would I ensure that the displayed list contents cannot be changed from the consolidated view?

n.b. I can't use Infopath or Designer

Comment: Simply give users only read permissions on these lists.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What about the best way to amalgamate the various rota lists into one screen? Is a web part page best?